# Why would Woocommerce Paypal guest checkout not work for my customers but making payments with a PayPal account does?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I’m using WooCommerce and for some reason, folks can pay with logging in to PayPal but not as guests.

The order shows up in WooCommerce and it’s pending - then it switches to canceled status and payment doesn’t get sent to me. guest checkout is enabled in PayPal.

Comment: It depends on the region they pay from - Which region customers cannot pay as a guest

Comment: See last line - https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/account-optional